# How to Update a Model's Boolean Attribute From Terminal

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I've got a boolean attribute on a Users model in my Phoenix application.

How can I update this attribute from my terminal/command prompt?

For example - in the Rails console (running `rails c` in my terminal) I can do something like this:

```
u = User.find(1)

u.admin = true

u.save
```

What's the best way to do this in Phoenix? (through `iex -S mix` maybe? - I think that's the closest thing to the `rails c`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that `iex -S mix` will open a console.

You have to use an Ecto.Changeset struct to make the change. [Ecto.Changeset.change/2](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#change/2) is the easiest way to make arbitrary changes:

```
alias MyApp.{Repo, User} # for convenience, not required
user = Repo.get(User, 1)
Ecto.Changeset.change(user, %{admin: true}) |> Repo.update!
```

Note that if you want to run your users validations when doing updates like this, you will probably want to use the function defined in your model (`changeset/2` by default).

Answer (score 2):

While @Gazler's answer is obviously correct, I think there is simpler way of getting the same result.

You could try something like:

```
u = App.Repo(User, 1) # corresponds to -> u = User.find(1)

u = %{ u | admin: true } # corresponds to -> u.admin = true

App.Repo.update(u) # corresponds to -> u.save
```

You need to be aware, with this approach the changes won't be a subject of validation, however, if you want to do simple and safe change, there might not be any need of reaching to `changeset`.

Hope that helps!